# How to prevent a member taking 2 roles

Tags: discord

I have a community server for university students.

And there are 4 roles that ProBot can give to users based on their reaction to his message. as you can see in this image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZZKB.png)

So, how can I prevent users from taking more than one role from those for roles?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Bot Dashboard]

This bot has a dashboard where you can change some options. One of them is called **Roles Limit Per User** so just set it to 1 and users will be able to receive only one role.